# Problem identifying the transaction hash for a new segwit uxto wallet

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, hash, transaction-id

How do I the transaction id or transaction hash of a new segwit wallet I just created and sent tokens to? The transaction hash I see from blochian.info refers to the hash of the previous transaction.

For example, I want to send bitcoin from bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn to another wallet and the transaction hash I see on blockchain.ifo is f0768c1159ab868300493e093261c1e78727b389b5c640c78f50fac3eb321d2e, which appears to be wrong.

How do I get the correct transaction hash or transaction ID for bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn?

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I [get] the transaction id or transaction hash of a new Segwit wallet**

A wallet has *many* addresses, not just one.

An address can be used in *many* transactions, not just one.

Therefore an active wallet is usually associated with many transactions, not just one.

Any Blockchain explorer will show a list of transactions that involve a specified address. For example, [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn),  [btscan](https://btcscan.org/address/bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn), [blockexplorer.one](https://blockexplorer.one/bitcoin/mainnet/address/bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn) and [blockcypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/bc1q9pjjydvzyqd8n83znsv6zhh56lk8yztj3m7cjn/) all show that address `bclq9p...7cjn` has only been involved in one *confirmed* transaction `f076...1d2e`

A Bitcoin wallet will usually also provide a way for someone to view a list of addresses used by that wallet and a list of transactions that have effectively sent money to or from addresses in that list.

> **I want to send Bitcoin [...] to another wallet**

To send money from one wallet to another, ask the receiving wallet for a new address. Use the sending wallet to send money to that new receiving address created by the receiving wallet.

Your sending wallet will find and select money you have previously received into the sending wallet.

Some wallet applications have a feature called "coin control" which might allow you to send amounts of money previously received at your choice of addresses from those under the control of your sending wallet.